# Error Printing through iframe - 'Undefined' Error when using Ctrl+P

Tags: jquery, printing

I have a document which pops up on the site within a jQuery Modal Box. The document has a print button at the end which just prints the document in the Pop-Up Box.

I wanted to print the document, only within the iframe, through Ctrl+P. That required preventing default behavior of printing all the page including the background.

This is the jQuery Code for the printing:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if ( ( (event.ctrlKey == true) || (event.metaKey == true) ) && (event.which == '80')) {
            event.preventDefault();
            printAssessment();
        }

});

function printAssessment() {
    if ($('#frameContainer').length) {
        $('#lightboxFrame')[0].contentWindow.print();    
    }

}
```

The HTML for my page with the iframe is below:

```
 <div id="frameContainer">
      <iframe id="lightboxFrame" width="950px" scrolling="auto" height="500px">
         <!DOCTYPE html>
           <html>
             <head>
                <body> (Whole Document in a Div) </body>
             ...
```

Now, the problem is that when I open up my modal box and press Ctrl+P, it prints if I don't scroll the modal, in the way I want it to be. But if I scroll the modal, and then press Ctrl+P, it gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of undefined
```

Strangely, even though when iframe is open, it still finds it undefined, but only when I scroll the modal iframe. If I just open the modal and press Ctrl+P, it prints fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Use keypress event instead of keydown

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
if ( ( (event.ctrlKey == true) || (event.metaKey == true) ) && (event.which == '80')) {
        event.preventDefault();
        printAssessment();
    }

});
```

Hope It will works.

Comment: What does the event have to do with `contentWindow`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `$('#lightboxFrame')` isn't returning any elements. What if you change

```
if ($('#frameContainer').length) {
```

to

```
if ($('#lightboxFrame').length) {
```

?